# Which data structure to use in python for coding a 2 column table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, formula

I would like to code the following table

[image: two column table]

I am thinking of having a function where I can input for example "tropical zone" and then to return me `n = 0.8` and `n1 = 0.9`
I was thinking to make use a dictionary. Is this the most appropriate data structure to use in this case?

```
def navigationcoefficients (type,key):
    if type == 'n':
        dict = {'unrestricted navigation': 1, 'summer zone': 0.9, 'tropical zone': 0.8, 'coastal zone': 0.8, 'sheltered area': 0.65}
        return dict[key]
    if type == 'n1':
        dict = {'unrestricted navigation': 1, 'summer zone': 0.95, 'tropical zone': 0.9, 'coastal zone': 0.9, 'sheltered area': 0.65}
        return dict[key]

n = navigationcoefficients('n','unrestricted navigation')
n1 = navigationcoefficients('n1','unrestricted navigation')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nope. Use something from [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html), or if you want: [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Ofc it also dependes on your use-case and access-patterns which you did not describe.

Comment: you can use a nested dictionary to get rid of the function `navigationcoefficients `. Pandas could be an overkill for a table of this size, but simplifies more complex queries...

Comment: Agree with elcombato, a nested dictionary would be a good idea. For tables of larger sizes pandas might do the trick. Another idea: a list of dictionaries where each dictionary has keys `"notation"`, `"coef n"` and `"coef n0"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do that I would prefer set a class to hold row data, something like:

```
class NamedTuple:
    def __init__(self, n, n1):
        self.n = n
        self.n1 = n1

data = {
    "Unrestricted navigation": NamedTuple(1.00, 1.00),
    "Summerzone": NamedTuple(0.90, 0.95)
    # ...
}

data["Summerzone"].n # access n of summer zone
```

And later you can add helper functions for this class.

When the calculation get more complex, you could wrap `list` or `dict` with a class to control your rows finer.

Comment: very interesting approach! Thank you!

Comment: For class that small/simple, I'd just use a `NamedTuple`

Comment: @Chazeon No, I mean this: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of dictionary, json and array.

example :

```
array = []
navigationDetails = {"Unrestricted Navigations":{"n1":"1.00","n2":"1.00"}}
array.append(navigationDetails)
navigationDetails = {"Summer Zone":{"n1":"0.90","n2":"0.95"}}
array.append(navigationDetails)
```

**Points to remember**

- This way you can search using zone. But this is very slower as you have to traverse all the elements.
- Use this when you don't want to delete or modify the elements.

Comment: I do not think dictionaries with just one key are a good idea. Better you introduce a third key called `"navigation notation"`.

Comment: It depends on your requirement. If you want to search frequently than you need another dictionary which keep tracks of your indexes of navigation notation and using that you can search. If you want to delete from the middle of an array and if sequence matters for you than you can create linked list kind of a structure.